# Characterizing Solar Panel Efficiency Based On Lumen Input

Tags: solar-cell

I'm new to the solar power field. I am trying to mathematically determine the output of a PV system based on the amount of lumens being directed onto the system. I have a lux meter which I plan to take periodic samples to see how much light will be hitting the system.  I am having trouble finding the correlation between incoming lumens and output power. I see a lot about peak power, but at what lumen threshold is this achieved?

Comment: Not just lumens but presumably spectrum too. Do you know the spectral response of your light meter & panels?

Comment: I do not have panels yet, that is part of the equation. I am hoping the characterization can be determined independent of the panel, and then a panel chosen based on optimal efficient matching characteristics. Regarding the spectral response, it is peaks around 580nm. It's a cheap meter, datasheet can be seen [here](http://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Technical/DataSheets/Dilog/TMDL7030_Manual.pdf).

Comment: If you're shopping for solar panels then presumably the manufacturer or sales vampire should be able to answer your question?

Comment: Sure, but I'm not "shopping for solar panels." I'm trying to determine the theory and application behind solar efficiency as a system. I don't believe they are the proper source.